# Powershell script to change cosmosDB throughput gives 401 error

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cli

I am trying to change cosmosDB throughput using powershell

When I run the following script, I it gives me this error but it work fine after that

> Get Token request returned http error: 401 and server response:
>   {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS50012: Invalid
>   client secret is provided.\r\nTrace ID: GUID\r\nCorrelation ID:
>   GUID\r\nTimestamp: 2019-01-30
>   03:59:07Z","error_codes":[50012],"timestamp":"2019-01-30
>   03:59:07Z","trace_id":"GUID","correlation_id":"GUID"}

```
$SecurePw = ConvertTo-SecureString $DeploymentServicePrincipalPassword -AsPlainText -Force
az login --service-principal -u $DeploymentServicePrincipalId -p $SecurePw --tenant $TenantId
az account set --subscription $SubscriptionId
az cosmosdb collection update --collection-name $CollectionName --name $AccountName --db-name $DBName --resource-group $ResourceGroupName --throughput $Throughput
```

If I don't convert the password to secure string, then it just works fine. How can I fix above script so that it does not give me the 401 error?

Thanks

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?If so,you could mark it to end this case, thank you very much,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the second line of following code and it works me.

```
$SecurePw = ConvertTo-SecureString '<your secret>' -AsPlainText -Force
$AzPass = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($SecurePw));
az login --service-principal -u '<your client id>' -p $AzPass --tenant '<your tenant id >'
```

Please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/authenticate-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest#sign-in-with-a-service-principal).

***Output:***

[image]

Comment: This will solve the issue  but this is useful only if you are using interactive mode.

Comment: @MohitVerma-MSFT But I tested by myself without interactive mode and it works too.

Comment: my bad, i was using $securePass =  Read-Host "Azure password: " -AsSecureString instead $SecurePw = ConvertTo-SecureString '<your secret>' -AsPlainText -Force. Resulting a prompt windows for password.